# Naked 'extends' keyword

Tags: scala

I was puzzling through the [Lift Cookbook for AJAX Forms](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#Forms), and I ran across the following object declaration:

```
object EchoForm extends {
```

This was confusing, so I tried it out, and it compiled fine. My Eclipse IDE doesn't seem to indicate that any additional features were inherited, but I suppose I don't trust keywords that are just 'hanging out'. Does this 'naked' `extends` do anything, or is it parsed as 'extends nothing in particular'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just came up on the ML:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/_qMoODIBQtE

followed by an itchy finger to deprecate the syntax:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/8zlyUH3S7sU/0EFiLSx9B68J

Here is the link to the syntax:

https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/2.10.x/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L272

Basically, `object Foo { }` is the same as `object Foo extends { }`.

Footnote: the snippet in question is withless:

```
object EchoForm extends {
  def render = {
    //snip
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**It's not an early object initialization section!** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675521/406435).

There [should be](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/2.10.x/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L274) `Parent` for `early object initialization`, but in code sample from the book there is no parents:

```
object EchoForm extends {
  def render = {
    ...
  }
} // no parents here!
```

**Old answer** (before @som-snytt mentioned it's **wrong**):

<s>It's</s> It could be (with parents) an early object initialization section. Take a look at this example:

```
trait Test {
  val i: Int
  val j = i + 1
}
```

Wrong creation of an instance:

```
object TestObj extends Test { val i = 1 }
TestObj.j
// Int = 1
```

`j` is initialized before `i`, but `j` depends on `i`.

Correct creation:

```
object TestObj extends { val i = 1 } with Test
TestObj.j
// 2
```

Early object initialization section allows initialize fields before all fields from inherited traits.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I didn't even think to think of the braces as being an element of initialization rather than the body of the object itself. #toomuchjavatoolittlefunctional

Comment: Sorry, no, it's actually not early definition syntax. And so many upvotes, too.

Comment: @NathanielFord, please accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20675521/406435). My answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this 'naked' extends do anything, or is it parsed as 'extends nothing in particular'?

It extends the 'inline' anonymous class immediately after the word `extends`:

```
object EchoForm extends <definition of anonymous class here - within brackets, optionally followed by `with` clauses for trait mixins>
```

Comment: Actually this is wrong. The production `ClassTemplateOpt` in the syntax has an alternative with an optional `extends` followed by the bracketed body. We're just used to seeing it without the extends keyword. You can see there's no anon class by `typeOf[X.type].baseClasses`. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html